# How to continuously delivery SQL-based app?

Tags: sql, database, continuous-deployment

I'm looking to apply continuous delivery concepts to web app we are building, and wondering if there any solution to protecting the database from accidental erroneous commit. For example, a bug that erases whole table instead of a single record.

How this issue impact can be limited according to continuous delivery doctorine, where the application deployed gradually over segments of infrastructure?

Any ideas?

Comment: Continuous deployment and recovery from errors are entirely different concepts.  Recovery from errors is typically ensured by a combination of full and incremental backups.  To some extent, you can prevent errors by hiring good developers and DBA's, and having  a good QA team.

Comment: My question is more how to limit the impact of erroneous query, in case it passed all testing and checks before it made to production.

Comment: I think you will find it incredibly difficult to even *define* what makes an erroneous query.  There's no replacement for a good QA strategy and ~100% coverage test cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well first you cannot tell just from looking what is a bad SQL statement. You might have wanted to delete the entire contents of the table. Therefore is is not physiucally possible to have an automated tool that detects intent.

So to protect your database, first make sure you are in full recovery (not simple) mode and  have full backups nightly and transaction log backups every 15 minutes or so. Now you cannot lose much information no matter how badly the process breaks. Your dbas should be trained to be able to recover to a point in time. If you don't have any dbas, I'd suggest the best thing you can do to protect your data is hire some. This is a non-negotiable in any non-trivial database environment and it is terribly risky not to have trained, experienced dbas if your data is critical to the business.

Next, you need to treat SQL like any other code, it should be in source control in scripts. If you are terribly concerned about accidental deletions, then write the scripts for deletes to copy all deletes to a staging table and delete the content of the staging table once a week or so. Enforce this convention in the code reviews.  Or better yet set up an auditing process that runs through triggers. Once all records are audited, it is much easier to get back the 150 accidental deletions without having to restore a database. I would never consider having any enterprise application without auditing.

All SQL scripts without exception should be code-reviewed just like other code. All SQL scripts should be tested on QA and passed before moving to porduction. This will greatly reduce the possiblility for error. No developer should have write rights to production, only dbas should have that. Therefore each script should be written so that is can just be run, not run one chunk at a  time where you could accidentally forget to highlight the where clause. Train your developers to use transactions correctly in the scripts as well.

Comment: Thanks for the great reply. Just a question - how exactly we can set an auditing process for the triggers? Are there any tools for that?

Comment: @Syber, thsi woudl a a database sepcific thing, what backend are you suing?

Comment: The DB is Pecona's MySQL. The back-end is J2EE.

Answer (score 1):

Your concern is bad data happening to the database.  The solution is to use full logging of all transactions so you can back out of transactions that you want to.  This would usually be used in a context of full backups/incremental backups/full logging.

SQL Server, for instance, allows you to restore to a point in time (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190982(v=sql.105).aspx), assuming you have full logging.

If you are creating and dropping tables, this could be an expensive solution, in terms of space needed for the log.  However, it might meet your needs for development.

You may find that full-logging is too expensive for such an application.  In that case, you might want to make periodic backups (daily?  hourly?) and just keep these around.  For this purpose, I've found LightSpeed to be a good product for fast and efficient backups.

Answer (score 0):

One of the strategies that is commonly adopted is to log the incremental sql statements rather than a collective schema generation so you can control the change at a much granular levels:

```
ex: 
change 1:
UP:
Add column
DOWN:
Remove column

change 2:
UP:
Add trigger
DOWN:
Remove trigger
```

Once the changes are incrementally captured like this, you can have a simple but efficient script to upgrade (UP) from any version to any version without having to worry about the changes that happening. When the change # are linked to build, it becomes even more effective. When you deploy a build the database is also automatically upgraded(UP) or downgraded(DOWN) to that specific build.

We have an pipeline app which does that at CloudMunch.