# Rollback on Continuous Deployment with Hudson and Maven

Tags: maven, hudson, continuous-deployment

In continuous deployment world, rollback is a tough topic.

I need to rollback to my latest version.

I use **Hudson** and **Maven**, and I want to deploy to a Java EE application server like JBOSS.

Eg.

```
<build>
    [...]
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.jboss.as.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-as-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>7.6.Final</version>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Any idea?

Comment: Rollback can be tough, right. It's even tougher to have an idea without knowing a bit more about your environment than the tools you use and a single plugin section.

Answer (score 4):

It depends from the technology and from the CD tool used.

For instance, Weblogic has the option to mark the replaced package as "[retitred](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs92/deployment/redeploy.html)" and to reactivate it.

```
mvn  com.oracle.weblogic:weblogic-maven-plugin:redeploy  
    -Dadminurl=t3://myhost:7001 -Duser=weblogic -Dpassword=mypassword 
    -Dtargets=AdminServer -Dname=sample.war
```

but the version (in the Manifest) must be different.

Generaly speaking when you build an application you will assign a version number, then you can restore the latest version storing the history of your versions.

In your case (Hudson-CI with Maven) **you may use a DB (MySQL of MantisBG in my case) to store the version of the packages just released**, then you are able to rollback easily.

A little explaination can be found here [Maven Build Cuistomization](https://www.packtpub.com/application-development/maven-build-customization).

Sometime, we do not deploy only one application but several packages with a "Parent Version":

- MyProject Release 1.0.1

  - MyApp.ear 1.3
  - MyBatch.jar 2.0

then you need a more complex CD system; in my case I use the hierarchy proposed by my Bug Tracker (MantisBT), but there are a lot of tools more professional see also [Continuous Delivery Scenario - implementing Rollback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18356741/continuous-delivery-scenario-implementing-rollback)

Comment: A bit hard to look inside an unpublished book.